# MacOS Finder Status Bar

Tags: macos, finder

Is it my imagination, or has the Finder status bar been relocated? I always look for it at the bottom of the window, but I find it at the top.

[image]

Various images on the Web with instructions for showing the status bar also show it at the bottom.

Comment: What do you consider to be a "status bar"? Pictures might help.

Comment: It’s that bar which shows the number of items and the available disk space. You can toggle it with `View | Show/Hide Status Bar` (`⌘/`).

Comment: OK, got it. Answer coming up...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is something that's got forgotten about over the years. It's 'interactive' but not really in a good way.

If you disable the Toolbar, this also disables the Sidebar & pushes the Status Bar to the top. Whilst set like this, View Sidebar is greyed out.

[image]

Re-enabling the Toolbar drops it back to the bottom & brings back the Sidebar if it was previously enabled.

[image]

<sup>Pictures from Mojave, but it's been this way for years.</sup>

I just realised, you appear to have managed a hybrid view. You have the Sidebar but not the Toolbar. I cannot repro this on Ventura, Big Sur, Mojave, El Capitan… or even Snow Leopard.

*Edit:*
From comments, there's a trick to getting the sidebar without the toolbar. You literally have to grab it as it slides away & drag it back into place. It might take a couple of attempts to succeed.
If you close & reopen the window, the sidebar is again gone.

[image]

Comment: I never noticed that the toolbar moves the status bar around. After playing with the tool bar, you can separately show or hide the status bar. Apple has a tendency to not document things clearly on the grounds that it’s all obvious. It’s not.

Comment: What do you consider "playing with the Toolbar."? As I said, I cannot repro your actual visible structure on any OS [I must have first noticed this foible maybe a decade ago] https://i.stack.imgur.com/YE1kq.png

Comment: I meant toggling it on or off.

Comment: I cannot repro - tested right back to El Capitan, same behaviour, Toolbar off, Sidebar vanishes & cannot be reinstated. I don't know how you managed to enable that hybrid view. https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PzTw.png

Comment: Neither do I. I can’t get that view back.

Comment: At least it proves I'm not going slowly round the bend;)) It would be interesting to figure out if it's reproducible by some intricate method, but I've never seen it that way before. Let's just call it a glitch.

Comment: To complete the set… I tested this back to Snow Leopard. Still the same - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WYwU.png

Comment: With the sidebar and the double arrow to grab it visible, press ⌥ ⌘ T and straight away, when the hiding of the toolbar happens, grab the sidebar.  Apart from the sidebar you can then even bring back the toolbar (customize) with the status bar staying at the top.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/wF4VafX.mp4